# What does "Given my reverence for, but ignorance of, the Bible, …." mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Can someone please explain the meaning of the passage below?

> "Bruce could quote the Bible at will, and did so to an amazing degree. Given my reverence for, but ignorance of, the Bible, it all sounded completely convincing."

*[Whose Word is It?](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=lcrUAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA3&lpg=PA3&dq=%22Given%20my%20reverence%20for,%20but%20ignorance%20of,%20the%20Bible%22&source=bl&ots=ARsdVyYhy9&sig=NzVRBSeKoaiu5SoZSGEi2cQr4y0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi36_zX-ebdAhXM0VMKHVFlBA0Q6AEwAnoECAwQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Given%20my%20reverence%20for%2C%20but%20ignorance%20of%2C%20the%20Bible%22&f=false): The Story Behind who Changed the New Testament and Why*

Comment: No, could **you** please explain what it is you don't understand in the text. It seems pretty straight forward to me.

Comment: It means there are five common situations that can contribute to distortion of what the Bible actually says. There are also too many commas in the second sentence.

Answer (score 1):

It means the person greatly respects and admires the Bible, but they are not educated in the content of the Bible.

Because of the "but ignorance of" piece, it feels like they are talking about being misled into believing something untrue by Bruce because of Bruce's knowledge of and their respect for the book. More context from the book would help clarify this.